# Problem in reading ROOT Trees and Branches

Tags: c++, root-framework

I'm writing a ROOT macro to read a tree, this tree contains many branches but I'm only interested in three particular ones. The problem is that when I try to read them I get wrong values, in fact if I type "h76->Show(1)" it prints out the value of the branches for the entry 1. When I try to read it from my macro and print, it gives me a wrong value.
This is my code:

```
#define N_PID 10000

void pTdist()
{
    Double_t pT;
        int i;
    Int_t PID[N_PID];
    Int_t ntrack; //Number of particles in one event
    TFile *file = new TFile("PROVA0.root","read");
    file->ls();
    TTree * Tout= (TTree*)file->Get("h76");
    Tout->Print();
    Int_t nentries=Tout->GetEntries();
    Tout->SetBranchStatus("*", false);
    //Tout->SetBranchStatus("ntrack", true); //In the ROOT tutorial it says that this operation is necessary but if I do it gives me error
    //Tout->SetBranchStatus("PID", true);
    //Tout->SetBranchStatus("pT", true);

    cout << " nentries = " << nentries << endl; //Here prints the correct number of entries
    Tout->SetBranchAddress("ntrack",&ntrack);
    Tout->SetBranchAddress("pT",&pT);
    Tout->SetBranchAddress("PID",&PID); //Fino a qui funziona tutto in teoria
    for( i=0;i< 10;i++)
    {
        //cout << i << endl;
        Tout->GetEntry(i); //
                printf("%d %d\n",ntrack,i);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks to everyone who will answer.

I tried to print the "ntrack" value for each entry comparing it with the one I get from the command show() but they don't match.

Comment: Allocating an array of length 10,000 on the stack is not good practice, but not sure if it is the cause of your problem.

Comment: The root cause is probably not enabling the branches you care about, but you did not tell us which error you got so we cannot help you furhter.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, you're right, I wasn't very descriptive the error I get enabling the Branches with the command "SetBranchStatus" is:
 *** Break *** segmentation violation

Comment: Anyway I'll try to repost this in a minimal reproducible way, thank you for the observations

Answer (score 1):

with Tout->SetBranchStatus("*", false); you're disabling all the branches, so you can't access them after that